# How to compile a C++ program in Xcode 3.2.3?

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation, xcode3.2

I want to know how I can compile a C++ program with Xcode 3.2.3? In the previous version of Xcode, there was a C++ tool available for command line utility. However, after I upgraded to the latest version of Xcode 3.2.3, these options are gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're still there - on the left side pick "Mac OS X Application", then in the pane that comes up, pick "Command Line Tool".  There is a pop-up button for Type, where you can pick "C++ stdc++".